# Why does nested fadeToggle fire twice?

Tags: jquery, fade

The nested fadeToggle on '#hero-text' in this jQuery fires twice when I click the 'hero' ID and I'm trying to figure out why, and how to fix this behavior.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#hero').click(function() {
            $('.non-hero').fadeToggle(800, function() {
                $('#hero-text').fadeToggle();
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: Paste the markup, please. Or create a jsfiddle showing the behavior.

Comment: +1 - we let's see your markup. Quite likely you may need to use `e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: Here's a link to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattdionis/GbgvH/1/). As you click the boxes you'll notice the nested fadeToggle fires twice each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered this from time to time. You can spend time trying to figure out why, but if you want a quick solution, here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#hero').off().click(function() {
            $('.non-hero').fadeToggle(800, function() {
                $('#hero-text').fadeToggle();
            });
        });
});
```

The above answer will solve the case in which '#hero' is getting an extra bind. However, another case you might be running into is if '.non-hero' is used in more than one spot. That function is going to fire for each instance of it, and then cause separate events to trigger fadeToggle on '#hero-text'.

Based on your jsfiddle, try this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#hero').click(function() {
            $('.non-hero').fadeToggle(800);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#hero-text').fadeToggle();
            }, 800);
        });
        $('#primary').click(function() {
            $('.non-primary').fadeToggle(800);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#primary-text').fadeToggle();
            }, 800);
        });
        $('#secondary').click(function() {
            $('.non-secondary').fadeToggle(800);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#secondary-text').fadeToggle();
            }, 800);                    
        });
    });
```

And for giggles I posted an alternative jsfiddle for you to consider:

http://jsfiddle.net/GbgvH/3/

Comment: Unfortunately '.non-hero' is used in more than one spot, and it looks like that's what's causing it to fire multiple times.

Comment: Simple solution then, all you need to do is add scope to either the '.non-hero' fade out, or add scope to the '#hero-text'. You'll need to post the rest of your markup if you need a more specific answer than that.

Comment: Here's a link to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattdionis/3ep4M/). I understand the basics of scoping, but this one is still tripping me up.